# javascript правильное положение элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу понять, как правильно дописать функцию. Функция выполняется при загрузке страницы и должна располагать элементы на сером фоне правильно от бортов и размер самих белых окон(элементов).
В данный момент, при передвижение элементов, отправляются следующие значение - `left, top, width, height`. `left` и `top` - это положение элемента на сером элементе. `width` и `height` размер самих белых элементов.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Draggable - Snap to element or grid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
    .draggable2 {
        width: 90px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        font-size: .9em;
        margin-left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 300px;
    }

    .draggable3 {
        width: 90px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        font-size: .9em;
        margin-left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 300px;
    }

    .ui-widget-header p,
    .ui-widget-content p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Разрешение экрана нужно получать */

    #snaptarget {
        height: 270px;
        width: 480px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .ui-resizable-helper {
        border: 2px dotted #000000;
    }

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#draggable2").draggable({
            snap: ".ui-widget-header",
            snapMode: "outer",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,1);
            }
        }); /* Перемещение объекта */
        $("#draggable2").resizable({
            helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
            containment: "#snaptarget",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,1);
            }
        }); /* Увелечение/Уменьшение объекта */
        $("#draggable3").draggable({
            snap: ".ui-widget-header",
            snapMode: "outer",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,2);
            }
        }); /* Перемещение объекта */
        $("#draggable3").resizable({
            helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
            containment: "#snaptarget",
            stop:function(){
                getPosSize(this,2);
            }
        }); /* Увелечение/Уменьшение объекта */
    });

    function getPosSize(EL,channel){ var Rect=EL.getBoundingClientRect(); var papa=snaptarget.getBoundingClientRect(); alert('top: '+(Rect.top-papa.top)+'px\nleft: '+(Rect.left-papa.left)+'px\nwidth: '+EL.offsetWidth+'px\nheight: '+EL.offsetHeight+'px'); 
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="snaptarget" class="ui-widget-header">
<div id="chan_1"></div>
<div id="chan_2"></div>
</div>

<br style="clear:both">



<div id="draggable2" class="draggable2 ui-widget-content">
    <p>CHANNEL 1</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable3" class="draggable3 ui-widget-content">
    <p>CHANNEL 2</p>
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Предпологаю, что скрипт скрипт должен выглядеть вот так

```
window.onload = function(EL, channel){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/get_win2_output_2",
                processData: true,
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var get_win2_output_2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("div[id='draggable3']").css({
                        left: get_win2_output_2.left,
                        top: get_win2_output_2.top,
                        width: get_win2_output_2.width,
                        height: get_win2_output_2.height

                    })
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/get_win1_output_1",
                processData: true,
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var get_win1_output_1 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("div[id='draggable2']").css({
                        left: get_win1_output_1.left,
                        top: get_win1_output_1.top,
                        width: get_win1_output_1.width,
                        height: get_win1_output_1.height
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

Но положение белых элементов тут не правильно.

Comment: Что значит тут "не правильно"? Что вернул аякс запрос? Если он все верно вернет, то должно работать. Например:
$("div[id='draggable3']").css({left: 100, top: 20, width: 150, height: 30})

Comment: @SergeyOmelchenko размер элемента правильный.. а вот положение в этом сером окне(элементе), не правильное.